# Is there any way to execute a SQL Server procedure from an Oracle stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, plsql

I have a SQL Server procedure which I want to call from an Oracle stored procedure and get the result. Then I need to do some processing on the data.

Can I create something like DB link to call the procedure? Or is there any possible way to do that?

Comment: Can you please clarify your question and provide more details at the moment it is far to obscure and broad for anyone to assist you.  I am guessing that you have a procedure on a SQL Server database, that you want to call from a Oracle Stored procedure?  If this is the case then http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/188879 may be a good place to start

Comment: thank you, and yes that is my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue solved by contacting DBA and creating gateway then using DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH with db link assigned with username, password and database